# How to make text in read-only text box not faded?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight puzzle game that is sort of like sudoku. I have text boxes for each cell of the puzzle. The player is given numbers to start out with and I don't want them to be able to edit those cells so I made them read only, but the color becomes faded and hard to read. What I'm trying to do is change the color of the text but no matter what I change it to it stays the same faded color. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not use TextBlock instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to edit the template of the textbox in expression blend. Its states would have a read-only state which you need to tweak to your satisfaction. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The way the TextBox does this is not to alter the colour but the opacity. To change this you'll need to re-style the TextBox and tweak the opacity for the correct Visual State.

If you haven't worked with Expression Blend too much then you'll want to look up tutorials on "Editing Control Templates" and the "Visual State Manager".

Answer (score 1):

The fastest, easiest way is to make a rectangle with 0% opacity cover up the box, and then don't actually make it read only.  The rectangle will block any tap action from the user, and if you want to make it editable later, you can collapse the rectangle.

Sure, its not "correct" but it works and its easy.